# How to make use of Etag with Firestore(REST Api) for detecting stale data?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to make use of e-tag for a particular collection/document in firestore?
If so, are the requests charged the same usual way?

Comment: Hey Ayyappa. Did you make any progress on this? I tried to help with an answer below. Did you have a chance to check that out. I hope it makes sense, despite possibly not what you were hoping for.

Comment: Sorry @FrankvanPuffelen I was just checking if any alternatives and totally accept your answer as it answers the given question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether the Firestore REST API support conditional gets using an `ETag` header. But even if it does, I expect you will be charged for reading the document as the call requires the server to read the document.

Comment: Thanks Frank for being helpful on time, always :)